# How can I include extra library/package in Databricks pyspark notebook?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Often the case we need to import some extra libraries in pyspark, Databricks provides a great environment for practicing pyspark, however, is it possible to install needed library there? if yes, how?

or is there any workaround to use non-builtin library/package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so depends on the case and package type. If it is PyPI package then the easiest way is using

```py
dbutils
```

```py
dbutils.library.installPyPI("pypipackage", version="version", repo="repo", extras="extras")
```

Or you could attach a library to a cluster. More info can be found here
https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html#install-workspace-libraries